# MPMoviePlayerController not refreshing or accessing m3u8 on Live HTTP Streaming

Tags: iphone, http, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, live

I have a Live HTTP Streaming system working on a web server, and I want to see the stream on the iPhone. To achieve that, I instantiate a new MPMoviePlayerController and initialize it with the URL of the .m3u8 playlist, but I'm having some problems:

- If I try it with an already generated playlist, with the streaming already stopped, I get the audio but just the first frames of the video.
- But, when I try to play the stream while generating and updating the playlist, the **movieplayer loads it, displays the first frames and hangs**, like trying to load the list again.

I have tried displaying the stream in mobile Safari, with html5 video tag, and the behavior is the same. Any idea why this happens? Could this be some web server configuration problem? I'm using Glassfish atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it: It simply **works in the device, but not on the simulator**. I have no clue why.

It also doesn't care if you implement it through html5 or through MPMoviePlayerController, the behavior is the same.

I hope it helps someone in the future.